# In a @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationship, how to set a property for the "many" entity when the other null and they is mapped by that property

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

I have a @OneToMany relationship: one team - many students. The Team entity use @EmbeddedId to define the main key with two column "teamId" and "classId" so when mapping with Student, I can detach them and must use @JoinColumn for all. My problem is: A Student in class don't have to join any team. This means the Team can null but the "classId" of the Student must not null (teamId NULL and classID NOT NULL in DB).

How can I set a uncertain value for the "classId" of Student when the Team is null?

I have tried following:

- Add @Column(name = "classId") classId property => mapping false because duplicate column name
- Add @Column(name = "classId", insertable = false, updateable = false) classId property and use setter to set value for it when Team is null => code run, set successfully but cannot insert into DB
- Use setter new Team() when Team is null then team.setClassId() => code run but when save student, the Team will also be saved => miss other properties of Team entity => can't save.

The Team Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
public class Team {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id"))
    @AttributeOverride(name = "classId", column = @Column(name = "classId"))
    private TeamId id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy(clause = "id ASC")
    private List<@Valid Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //Other properties
    
    // Constructors, getters, setters
}
```

The Student Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="students")
public class Student {
    @Id
    private int id;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teamId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "classId", referencedColumnName = "classId")
    private Team team;
    
    //Other properties
    
    // Constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Do you have a different entity for the Class?

Comment: No, classId is only thing we know about the class, but I need it when call api to define which class student or team in.